# Unable to get data of third party API with Token attached to it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I am trying to get data from a third-party API. It works on postman but I want to make a request and get the data from my to react project.

Here is the public API: `https://api.securityscorecard.io/companies/okta.com` where I can grab data about `okta.com`. and the token is `Token Qit1XE1nrE1NHYfIkzHH8MGxUwUO`.

It works fine on the postman. Take a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

**How can I make a valid request to get this data in react? Here is what I tried so far.**

```
axios({
      url: "https://api.securityscorecard.io/companies/okta.com",
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Token: "Qit1XE1nrE1NHYfIkzHH8MGxUwUO",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("okta data", response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

But It did not work. Where is my mistake here? Thanks

Comment: Probably not a great idea to share your token with the entire world.

Comment: It's a public API with token provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
    axios({
      url: "https://api.securityscorecard.io/companies/okta.com",
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Token Qit1XE1nrE1NHYfIkzHH8MGxUwUO",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("okta data", response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: that's great, then please mark my answer as the solution.